# DB2 z/OS update by list

Tags: sql, db2, zos

i have a list of 3k ID's in text file. I should find rows with such ID's and update them.
I would expect to work something like

```
WITH RECORD_ID
(ID) AS (
'12345',
...
'32134')
UPDATE MY_TABLE T
SET T.NAME = REPLACE(T.NAME, X'03', '')
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RECORD_ID R WHERE R.ID = T.ID);
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: "Doesn't work" how?  I'm not familiar with the z-os version, but the CTE doesn't appear to be valid in my i-os DB2.  If you're building a CTE, why not just put the list of ids in an `IN(...)` clause?

Comment: I thought that IN will be very slow if you have list with 3000 records. And searched for faster update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just have a list of values in a CTE in DB2, you have to `UNION ALL` the values together:

```
WITH RECORD_ID (ID) AS (
    SELECT '12345' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    -- ...
    SELECT '32134' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
UPDATE MY_TABLE T
SET T.NAME = REPLACE(T.NAME, X'03', '')
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RECORD_ID R WHERE R.ID = T.ID);
```

Should work.

I agree with @X-Zero, though... it seems that a list of values in an `IN` clause would be more appropriate, unless there's a specific reason you want to use the CTE.